# Make two consecutive scanfs

Tags: c, scanf

I have an input text in a single line of the form "part1 part2". How can i get in 2 different variables part1 and part2 if they have been input in the same line?

Comment: `scanf("%s%s",s1,s2);` Doesnt this work ??

Comment: always check how many inputs were actually assigned.

Comment: Yes, now that i check it, it does. The problem is that im quite new with C and i was thinking in java, where as far as i know, it is not allowed. Thanks for the answers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two different format specifiers :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char part1[100],part2[100];
    scanf("%99s%99s",part1,part2);
    printf("%s,%s\n",part1,part2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The space in `"%s %s"` is unnecessary, but OK to have. Better to use `"%99s%99s"` and limit input.